# Hive Case Statement for Insert Overwrite Directory

Tags: hadoop, parameters, hive, case, hiveql

When attempting to run an HQL script with the following logic, I receive the error:

```
ParseException line 4:0 cannot recognize input near 'CASE' 'WHEN' 'mytable' in serde properties specification
```

Script Logic

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/example/path'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
CASE WHEN ${hiveconf:tbl_name}='mytable'
THEN SELECT * FROM ${hiveconf:tbl_name} LEFT OUTER JOIN ...;
WHEN ${hiveconf:tbl_name}='mytable2'
THEN SELECT * FROM ${hiveconf:tbl_name} LEFT OUTER JOIN ...;
ELSE THEN
END
```

How can I correctly assign a select statement for the INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY to use based on the value of the tbl_name parameter which I am passing in?

Update 1:
When modifying as:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ${hiveconf:tbl_name}='mytable'
THEN * FROM WHEN ${hiveconf:tbl_name}='mytable'
WHEN ${hiveconf:tbl_name}='mytable2'
THEN * FROM ${hiveconf:tbl_name} LEFT OUTER JOIN ...;
ELSE THEN
END
```

It errors with:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 9:9 cannot recognize input near '*' 'FROM' 'mytable' in expression specification
```

Update 2:  When modifying as:

```
SELECT * CASE WHEN ${hiveconf:tbl_name}='mytable'
THEN FROM WHEN ${hiveconf:tbl_name}='mytable'
WHEN ${hiveconf:tbl_name}='mytable2'
THEN FROM ${hiveconf:tbl_name} LEFT OUTER JOIN ...;
ELSE THEN
END
```

It errors with:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 8:9 Failed to recognize predicate 'CASE'. Failed rule: 'regularBody' in statement
```

Comment: What you try to do is an outrage to the entity-relation concept. SQL cannot do that, by definition. You need a **procedural language** wrapper around SQL, like PL/SQL or T-SQL or PgSQL => *if A then run SQL query "INSERT SELECT FROM AAA" elseif B then run SQL query "INSERT SELECT FROM BBB" else ...*

Comment: For the record, Hive has a specific syntax for multi-table INSERT, but that is not standard SQL either (and that's not what you want, I know, just for the record) => *FROM AAA INSERT INTO MMM WHERE A='M' INSERT INTO PPP WHERE A='P' ...*

Comment: More to the point, Hive 2.0 has an immature-and-cumbersome-extension to wrap some procedural language around SQL: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=59690156

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution is to use UNION ALL+WHERE. Like this:

```
insert overwrite directory
...
select * from mytable where '${hiveconf:tbl_name}'='mytable'
union all
select * from mytable2 where '${hiveconf:tbl_name}'='mytable2'
```

Add your joins to each select.