# how to run a different select statement based on condition in Hive SQL

Tags: sql, select, hive, conditional-statements, hiveql

I would like to know how to run a different select statement based on condition in Hive SQL.

The following query does not work but throws an error.

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 4:2
>   cannot recognize input near '(' 'SELECT' '1' in expression
>   specification

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN '${UN}'!= '' THEN 
        (
        SELECT * 
            from table1 t 
            WHERE t.yymmddval BETWEEN '${D1}' AND '${D2}'
            AND t.un in ('${UN}')
        )
    ELSE
        (
        SELECT * 
            from table1 t 
            WHERE t.yymmddval BETWEEN '${D1}' AND '${D2}'
            AND t.un in (
               (SELECT
                o.unq_num as un
                FROM table2 as o
                WHERE o.date >= '2017-01-01'
                    AND upper(o.srl_num) in ('${R}')
                LIMIT 1)            
            )       
        )
    END
```

Comment: Similar question is already answered (Use UNION ALL+ WHERE instead of your CASE statement): https://stackoverflow.com/a/37696700/2700344  - just put your condition and reverse condition to the WHERE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use UNION ALL with your queries + add conditions for switching corresponding query:

```
 select * 
   from table1 t 
   where (t.yymmddval BETWEEN '${D1}' and '${D2}')
     and t.un in ('${UN}') 
     and '${UN}'!= '' --switching condition 

union all

select * 
  from table1 t 
 where (t.yymmddval BETWEEN '${D1}' AND '${D2}')
   and t.un in 
              (SELECT
               o.unq_num as un
               FROM table2 as o
               WHERE o.date >= '2017-01-01'
                   AND upper(o.srl_num) in ('${R}')
               LIMIT 1) 
    and '${UN}'= '' --switching condition
```

Comment: This is Egg of Columbus. Brilliant! I only had to put extra directive : 
set hive.mapred.mode=nonstrict; to allow for union all.
Thank you so much for help.